# Is my EBNF logic wrong here?

Tags: python, parsing, ebnf

I'm using [SimpleParse](http://simpleparse.sourceforge.net/) in a Python program in order to parse some rather simple linguistics.  It should be able to parse the following sample text (each line separately):

```
d6
(d4 + d8 + 5) + 6
{5d20}+12
[d10 + 6d6] + 9
(d10 + d12) + 8d8
```

I've written up the following EBNF for the above, but the parser keeps crashing on me, even on the simple case of "d6":

```
# 'number' is already predefined in SimpleParse to parse exactly what you think it will parse
root          := roll
roll          := space,operations,space
operations    := function+
function      := ((dice,op,function)/(grouping,op,function)/(function,op,grouping))/(dice/grouping/constant) #just to clarify, the '/' is a FirstOf operator
constant      := number
grouping      := ([[(],operations,[])])/'{',dice,'}'
dice          := number?,[dD],number
op            := space,[-+],space
space         := [ \t]*
```

I'm beginning to wonder if maybe I've gotten the logic in my EBNF wrong somewhere.

**EDIT:** For the curious, here is what the final EBNF looks like:

```
roll          := space,operations,space
operations    := function
function      := (dice,op,operations)/(grouping,op,operations)/dice/constant/grouping
constant      := number
grouping      := ('(',operations,')')/('{',dice,'}')/('[',operations,']')
dice          := number?,[dD],number
op            := space,[-+],space
space         := [ \t]*
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't defined `number`, and I don't see it predefined in the docs.

Comment: Sorry, I should have made a comment, but SimpleParse actually has a predefined library for 'number' that I've already included so that shouldn't be a problem.  I'll add that.

Comment: The only other thing I see is that you're grouping things a little oddly for `function`. Is that intended?

Comment: `number` doesn't include hex, does it? If it does, it would eat the `d`.

Comment: It appears `number` does not include hex. If no one else can help, all I can suggest is to copy and simplify, starting with a grammar for only the simplest case, and test at each stage as you build it up to the full grammar to see where the error comes in. Good luck.

Comment: That's a good question on the hex.  I didn't think of that.  I'll do some testing.  As far as the function is concerned, I wanted to be able to cover a few different cases of pairing it with an operation, and ending it appropriately.

Comment: After a bit of testing, it seems that no, the hex isn't an issue.

Comment: Yup, you were absolutely right, I had to start simple, and go from there.